# Laravel 8 return view blank page or white screen

Tags: php, html, laravel

I've got problem with my laravel 8..
I Created Controller for edit profile, and when i access the page, it return view blank page or white screen with no error..

Here's my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function edit(Request $request)
    {
        return view('profile.edit', [
            'user' => $request->user()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here's my route or web.php (Route for edit profile is at last)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard.index');
    Route::get('/categories/select', [App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController::class, 'select'])->name('categories.select');
    Route::resource('/categories', App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController::class);
    Route::get('/tags/select', [App\Http\Controllers\TagController::class, 'select'])->name('tags.select');
    Route::resource('/tags', App\Http\Controllers\TagController::class);
    Route::resource('/posts', App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class);
    Route::resource('/banners', App\Http\Controllers\BannerController::class);
    Route::resource('/clients', App\Http\Controllers\ClientController::class);
    Route::resource('/gallerys', App\Http\Controllers\GalleryController::class);
    Route::resource('/products', App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class);
    Route::resource('/services', App\Http\Controllers\ServiceController::class);
    Route::resource('/teams', App\Http\Controllers\TeamController::class);
    Route::resource('/testimonies', App\Http\Controllers\TestimonyController::class);
    Route::resource('/metas', App\Http\Controllers\MetaController::class);
    Route::resource('/keywords', App\Http\Controllers\KeywordController::class);
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'filemanager'], function () {
        Route::get('/index', [App\Http\Controllers\FileManagerController::class, 'index'])->name('filemanager.index');
        \UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
    });
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/profile', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    });
});
```

And here's my view

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('title')
Edit Profile
@endsection

@section('breadcrumbs')
{{ Breadcrumbs::render('edit_profile') }}
@endsection

@section('content')

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Update Profile
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.update') }}">
                            @method('patch')
                            @csrf
    
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
    
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name', $user->name) }}" autocomplete="name" autofocus>
    
                                    @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Username') }}</label>
    
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{{ old('username', $user->username) }}" autocomplete="username" autofocus>
    
                                    @error('username')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>
    
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email', $user->email) }}" autocomplete="email">
    
                                    @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Update Profile
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

I still work this at localserver, anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: are you move on this page? dump any variable and check it

Comment: share the full link that you used to access the view, is the file inside profile folder and is its name 'edit'?

Comment: It turns out happen in my controller because i not apply auth there.. Thankyou for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is issue in your controller code. Please try below code. I have changed user fetch syntax.

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class ProfileController extends Controller
    {
        public function edit(Request $request)
        {
            return view('profile.edit', [
                'user' => \Auth::user()
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it turns out happen in my controller because i not apply auth there.. Thankyou for your help!